Conexion a una base de datos utlizando un context herando DbContext
actualmente estamos buscando hacer la conexion a una base de datos para insertar los datos obtenidos de un API REST. Ya logramos contectarnos al API REST y deserializar los datos para tenerlos disponibles, de igual forma ya modelamos las tablas y creamos el la clase Context que nos permitira insertar los datos en la tabla. Con el animo de ilustrar la situacion, mostramos los puntos claves del proceso.
Estos son los modelos que estamos utilizando:
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DAL
{
    public class GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Registro { get; set; }   
        public BigInteger uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        [Precision(53)]
        [Column(TypeName = "float(53)")]
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueTotalFuel { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueFuelLevel1 { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueRPM { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueOdometer { get; set; }
        public string? CANValuesSpeed { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueCoolantTemperature { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueAmbientAirTemperature { get; set; }  
        public string? CANValueEngineHours { get; set; }
        public string? peripheralsValueMotor { get; set; }
        public string? geofencePolygon { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
    }
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        // 2024-10-24 16:29: Para identificar las tablas que se van a necesitar.
        public DbSet<GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet> GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet { get; set; }


        // 2024-10-24 16:29: el constructor del padre o clase heredada DbContext, es el que necesita un parametro y
        // por eso la nombre asi: base(options). Eso quiere decir que siempre que vaya a instanciar
        // un objeto con LicenciaContex, debo pasarle un argumento que cumpla con el parametro
        public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
        {
        }


        //Aqui pongo las claves combinadas de los modelos, ya que solo aqui se puede poner claves combinadas
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
    
}

Estas son los metodos que utilizamos:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using DAL;
using System.Xml;
using System.Dynamic;
using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace BIL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 2024-08-28: Se crean las variables sencibles.
    /// </summary>
    public class FlotasNetClient
    {
        // 2024-08-29: Creacion de las variables a obtener del appsettings.json
        private static string? _baseUrl;
        private static string? _username;
        private static string? _sha256Concatenado;
        private static string? _company;
        private readonly Context context;


        /// <summary>
        /// 2024-08-29: Constructor de la clase donde se pasan los datos sencibles de acceso.
        /// </summary>
        public FlotasNetClient(Context context)
        {
            // 2024-08-29: Con esta variable tengo el acceso al appsettings.json para tomar informacion de alli.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            // 2024-11-02 10:54: Datos para acceder al API REST.
            _baseUrl = builder.GetSection("baseUrl").Value;
            _username = builder.GetSection("username").Value;
            _sha256Concatenado = builder.GetSection("sha256Concatenado").Value;
            _company = builder.GetSection("company").Value;
            // 2024-11-16 21:53: Para tener acceso a la estructura de la tabla para luego poder insertar datos.
            this.context = context;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 2024-10-10 10:24: Obtenemos el JSON y con este, creamos la coleccion de objetos en C# para tener los datos disponibles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<vehicleInfo[]> GetVehicleInfoByDate()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {

                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://servicios.flotasnet.es:1443/api/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate=2024-10-29T06%3A35%3A00Z&enddate=2024-10-29T06%3A40%3A00Z"),
                Headers =
                {
                    { "user-agent", "vscode-restclient" },
                    { "accept", "application/json" },
                    { "user", _username },
                    { "password", _sha256Concatenado },
                    { "company", _company },
                },
            };
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                // 2024-09-13 11:19: Con esta linea se genera la pagina con los datos.
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // 2024-09-11 08:19: Con esta linea, vemos los datos en consola para hacer busquedas y ver lo que 
                // estamos recibiendo.
                Console.WriteLine(body);
                // 2024-09-13 11:19: Con esta linea se convierte la pagina llena de datos en una coleccion en C#.
                var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vehicleInfo[]>(body);
                return deserialized;
            }
        }


        public GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(vehicleInfo info) => new GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
        {
            uniqueID = info.uniqueID,
            plate = info.plate,
            GPSDate = info.GPSDate,
            speed = info.speed,
            odometer = info.odometer,
            receivedDate = info.receivedDate,
            stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateParam,
            stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail,
            CANValueTotalFuel = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueFuelLevel1 = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueRPM = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueOdometer = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValuesSpeed = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueCoolantTemperature = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueAmbientAirTemperature = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueEngineHours = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            peripheralsValueMotor = info.peripheralsInfo?.peripheralsData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.peripheralsParam == "Motor")?.peripheralsValue,
            geofencePolygon = info.geofenceInfo?.geofencePolygon
        };



        public async void InsertarDatosOperacion()
        {
            // 2024-08-29: Con esta variable tengo el acceso al appsettings.json para tomar informacion de alli.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            // 2024-11-02 10:54: Conexion a la base de datos.
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(builder.GetSection("flotasdb").Value);
            conexion.Open();
            var deserialized = await GetVehicleInfoByDate();
            var gpsDatas = deserialized.Select(ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet);
            context.GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet.AddRange(gpsDatas);
            context.SaveChanges();
            // 2024-11-02 15:03: Desconexion a la base de datos.
            conexion.Close();
        }


    }
}

Luego de tener todo estos, vamos al program.cs donde vamos a indicar el proceso a seguir asi:
using BIL;
using DAL;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


var client = new FlotasNetClient();
var vehicleData = await client.InsertarDatosOperacion();

Como pueden notar, aqui llamamos la clase principal FlotasNetClient() y luego llamamos al metodo encargado de insertar los datos en la base de datos, el cual se denomina client.InsertarDatosOperacion(). En este punto nos salen dos errores, los cuales son:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'context' of 'FlotasNetClient.FlotasNetClient(Context)'   BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Program.cs  8   Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS4008  Cannot await 'void' BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Program.cs  10  Active

Actualmente no tenemos muy claro el funcionamiento dle DbContext, lo que entendemos es que nos permite interactuar con la base de datos, pero no tenemos profundidad en su uso.
Debido a esto, notamos que el program.cs nos estan solicitando un argumento context, pero no sabes como se lo debemos pasar. De igual forma no tenemos muy claro el otro error que esta surgiendo.
Agradecemos la ayuda que nos puedan brindar para continuar avanzando con nuestra solucion.

Tienes que crear un objeto del tipo DbContextOptionsBuilder y usar una función adecuada según la base de datos, por ejemplo:
Para SQLite:
var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().UseSqlite(@"connection_string").Options;

Para SQL Server:
var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().UseSqlServer(@"connection_string").Options;

Evidentemente (pero igual lo voy a decir), donde puse connection_string debes poner el connection string adecuado para tu base de datos
Luego con esto puedes crear el DbContext
var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().UseSqlServer(@"connection_string").Options;
var context = new Context(option);
var client = new FlotasNetClient(context);


Yussef, realice los ajustes mencionados en el Program.cs, las cuales fueron: var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(builder.GetSection("flotasdb").Value).Options;
var context = new Context(option);
var client = new FlotasNetClient(context);  Luego fue necesario utlizar el paquete using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer; el nuget que descargue fue la version 7.0.20. Aun nos continua saliendo el error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS4008 Cannot await 'void' BIL
